# how to priorities different tests in a Testng XML

Tags: testng, testng.xml

I have few Test cases running for different Test class but my issue is that for in one test cases i have 100 scenarios and in another i have 40.

TestingDemo has 100 scenarios 
TestingClass has 40 scenarios 
TestingLogin has 10 scenarios

So is there any way to run TestingDemo test class first and complete it and then run the remaining test.

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="TestSuit" parallel="tests" thread-count="100">
    <test name="TestingDemo" parallel="instances" thread-count="50">
        <classes>
            <class name="demo.testing1"></class>
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="TestingClass" parallel="instances" thread-count="46">
        <classes>
            <class name="demo.testing"></class>
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="TestingLogin" parallel="instances" thread-count="4">
        <classes>
            <class name="demo.login"></class>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you disable parallelism i.e., set `parallel=none` at suite level, then the `<test>` would be executed in the order in which they were found in the test suite.